# Alternative to map_data('world') - Covers Antartica to -90

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for a simple alternative to `map_data('world')` as a data set with which to easily draw the countries of the world. Ideally it's easily implementable with `ggplot2`.

The problem is that I am graphing some geographic points, some of which appear close to -90 (S). When I use `map_data('world')` to get my polygons, I see that Antarctica doesn't run all the way to -90 (lowest lat value for Antarctica is -85.19218 - see code below). Thus anything further south than that shows as if its off the map, which doesn't look great.

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
library('ggplot2') #Import library
world = map_data('world') #Get polygon data
data = data.frame(lat = -86, long = 0) #Create geographic data with southerly value

#plot
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = world, 
               aes(y = lat, x = long, group = group), col = 'grey', fill = NA) +
  geom_point(data = data, 
             aes(y = lat, x = long), col = 'red')
```

Gives:
[image]

You can see the limits of the Antarctic extent as follows:

```
library('dplyr')
world %>% 
  filter(region == 'Antarctica') %>% 
  select(lat) %>% 
  min()
[1] -85.19218
```

Thus the problem is not the projection, its the data set. Does anyone know an alternative easily available rendering of the countries that has Antarctica running to -90?

Comment: There isn't a border or coastline at -90 degrees, so there's no data there.  There is a polygon that has its southermost vertex around -85, but the line wraps around the globe north of the pole.  I'm not sure there's a good  easy way to map the entire globe  on a flat plane with Antarctica showing up well.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Appreciate that this can't be done. If you put this as the answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any data for `ggplot2` to plot below about 85 degrees south in the `world` data as a polygon. Using `geom_polygon` also has the drawback of connecting the data from the far left (west) to the data on the far right(east).

To get around having the straight line above the red dot, use the `sf` package and `geom_sf` to plot spatial data.

I don't know of a good way to plot Antarctica along with the entire rest of the globe. If you are mostly interested in the southern pole & it's surroundings, an orthographic projection might work.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rnaturalearth)

world <- map_data('world') #Get polygon data
data = data.frame(lat = -86, long = 0) #Create geographic data with southerly value

#plot
p_polygon <- ggplot() +
               geom_polygon(data = world, 
                            aes(y = lat, x = long, group = group), col = 'grey', fill = NA) +
               geom_point(data = data, 
                          aes(y = lat, x = long), col = 'red')

# use rnaturalearth package to get coastline data in the sf format
world_sf <- ne_coastline(returnclass = 'sf')

# use geom_sf to plot the data
p_sf <- ggplot(world_sf) + 
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(data = data, aes(y = lat, x = long), col = 'red')

# geom_sf, using an orthographic projection
p_sf_ortho <- ggplot(world_sf) + 
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(data = data, aes(y = lat, x = long), col = 'red') +
 coord_sf( crs= "+proj=ortho +lat_0=-80 +lon_0=90")  

# the three plots together
cowplot::plot_grid(p_polygon, p_sf, p_sf_ortho,
                   labels = c('polygon', 'sf', 'sf orthographic'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Be careful with this though, because the data point is not projected, it can shift if you change the map projection. e.g. to show South America `coord_sf( crs= "+proj=ortho +lat_0=-40 +lon_0=-70")  `

Answer (score 0):

The {rnaturalearth} package has a good representation of Antarctica (and the other land masses too!)  I have switched to using it for all my background mapping.  This example:

```
world <-  rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf")

map_crs <- st_crs(3031) # WGS 84 / Antarctic Polar Stereographic

ggplot() + geom_sf(data = world %>% st_transform(map_crs)) +
  coord_sf(datum = map_crs,  
           ylim = c(-3e6,3e6),  
           xlim = c(-3e6,3e6))
```

Produces this map - there is just a tiny sliver of unmapped Antarctica:
[image: Map of Antarctica]

Comment: Thanks for this. I will take a look at the rnaturalearth polygons. For my original problem this isn't a solution, however as I don't just want an overhead of Antarctica, I was a map of the world showing all of Antarctica. As per the comment above, this isn't possible.

Comment: The naturalearth polygons cover Antarctica down to -89.9+ degrees or so.  You can use any projection you want, I chose polar stereographic to show the extent.